# Haskell Gloss and STM concurrency integration

Tags: haskell, stm, gloss

I want to update a Haskell Gloss GUI from multiple threads (4 threads).
I am looking at an application where an event on the Haskell `Gloss` GUI triggers a series of steps that end up creating threads each of which can and should change the GUI if need be. I am using the Gloss `play` function.

The Gloss GUI function `play` of type:

```
play
  :: Display
     -> Color
     -> Int
     -> world
     -> (world -> Picture)
     -> (Event -> world -> world)
     -> (Float -> world -> world)
     -> IO ()
```

Notice the parameter `(Event -> world -> world)` which is the function that handles the keyboard events.

If I click say **x** on the keyboard, then `handleKeys::Event -> world -> world` captures this `event`, takes a `world`(a model of my application which is a data structure for display by Gloss) and returns a `world` with or without changes.

Based on the event processed by `handleKeys::Event -> world -> world` other threads may be spawned using `forkIO :: IO () -> IO ThreadId`. These spawned threads should also manipulate the `world` and return a `world` for display. That is each thread runs a function of type `world->world`. I would then use STM primitives for concurrency. These primitives are:

```
    putTMVar :: TMVar a -> a -> STM ()
    takeMVar :: MVar a -> IO a
    atomically :: STM a -> IO a
    retry :: STM a
    orElse :: STM a -> STM a -> STM a
```

As you can already guess, the Haskell type-checker is giving me a migraine. Is there  possibility of running a Gloss application relying on STM concurrency to update the GUI without violating types?

Comment: Can't write an answer but you should use `playIO` from `Graphics.Gloss.Interface.IO.Game`

Comment: @monocell Valuable information, thumbs up.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but an alternate solution to updating gloss with multiple threads is to use the parallel library (which does not require IO) instead of the STM library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use playIO from Graphics.Gloss.Interface.IO.Game